# css3 columns wrong order

Tags: css

I am using css3 columns in order to create 3 columns per row order, like pinterest.

but it seems to sort this way:

1  |  4  |  7

2  |  5  |  8

3  |  6  |  9

instead of:

1  |  2  |  3

4  |  5  |  6

7  |  8  |  9

here is what I wrote:

```
.list .remains {
-webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
column-count: 2;

-webkit-column-gap: 0; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-gap: 0; /* Firefox */
column-gap: 0;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/uyv70h05/

is it it's natural behavior? can I fix it somehow?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behavior of columns, which are vertical. It looks like you want horizontal rows, which can be done by setting `float:left` or `display:inline-block` on all the individual elements in the list {1,2,3...}.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uyv70h05/1/

If the elements aren't the same height, like on pinterest, there's no way that I've found to replicate that without using javascript. There are several libraries that serve that purpose, Masonry being the one I've heard the most about: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on css3 but I think that the natural behavior is that way... a quick fix is to group elements by div copy and paste this code it may work... `

```
<div class="list">

    <div class="remains">
      <a class="item box" href="#">
        <img src="./img/usericon.png" alt="" class="user-icon" />
        <h3>1</h3>
        <p>What happened</p>
      </a>
      <a class="item box" href="#">
        <img src="./img/usericon.png" alt="" class="user-icon" />
        <h3>2</h3>
        <p>Hey How are you doing? you went missing lately... </p>
      </a>
    <a class="item box" href="#">
        <img src="./img/usericon.png" alt="" class="user-icon" />
        <h3>3</h3>
        <p>Dude... it was AWESOME!</p>
      </a>
    </div>
        <div class="remains">
    <a class="item box" href="#">
        <img src="./img/usericon.png" alt="" class="user-icon" />
        <h3>4</h3>
        <p>Please let it be fine...</p>
      </a>
    <a class="item box" href="#">
        <img src="./img/usericon.png" alt="" class="user-icon" />
        <h3>5</h3>
        <p>SHIT! I thing I got it wrong!!! ...</p>
      </a>
    <a class="item box" href="#">
        <img src="./img/usericon.png" alt="" class="user-icon" />
        <h3>6</h3>
        <p>ONE TWO ONE TWO ... SOUND CHECK.. Let's write something so long, it will go two rows!</p>
      </a>
            </div>
        <div class="remains">
    <a class="item box" href="#">
        <img src="./img/usericon.png" alt="" class="user-icon" />
        <h3>7</h3>
        <p>Seems like we have got some big issue around here ...</p>
      </a>
    <a class="item box" href="#">
        <img src="./img/usericon.png" alt="" class="user-icon" />
        <h3>8</h3>
        <p>NIGHTS IN WHITE SATIN.. NEVER REACHING ...</p>
      </a>
    <a class="item box" href="#">
        <img src="./img/usericon.png" alt="" class="user-icon" />
        <h3>9</h3>
        <p>NIGHTS IN WHITE SATIN.. NEVER REACHING ...</p>
      </a>

    </div>
 </div>
```

`

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying about that it start in the same y position. Can you explain your self what is the problem your  are facing? The question was that you wanted this behavior                                                        1 | 2 | 3

4 | 5 | 6

7 | 8 | 9 and the code that I posted gets the behavior your are looking... I am unavailable to upload an image to you because of my reputation...